# How to write Unicode data as Cyrillic symbols to file?

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv, unicode

I have some variables in Unicode.

```
title

 u'\u0410\u0434\u043c\u0438\u043d\u0438\u0441\u0442\u0440\u0430\u0442\u043e\u0440 \u0438\u043d\u0442\u0435\u0440\u043d\u0435\u0442-\u043c\u0430\u0433\u0430\u0437\u0438\u043d\u0430'

type(title)

 unicode
```

If I print this vaiable, I get:

```
 print (title)

  Администратор интернет-магазин
```

When I try to write this data (Cyrillic symbols) to CSV file:

```
 with open('avito.csv','a') as f:
      writer=csv.writer(f)
      writer.writerow((title))
```

This error occurs:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u0410' in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

How can I write this variable as Cyrillic symbols to a CSV?

Comment: You pasted the code a second time instead of the error message.

Comment: If you are going to be working with unicode you should really consider Python 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Three ways on Python 2.7.  Note that to open the files in Excel that program likes a UTF-8 BOM encoded at the start of the file.  I write it manually in the brute force method, but the `utf-8-sig` codec will handle it for you otherwise.  Skip the BOM signature if you aren't dealing with lame editors (Windows Notepad) or Excel.

```
import csv
import codecs
import cStringIO

title = u'\u0410\u0434\u043c\u0438\u043d\u0438\u0441\u0442\u0440\u0430\u0442\u043e\u0440 \u0438\u043d\u0442\u0435\u0440\u043d\u0435\u0442-\u043c\u0430\u0433\u0430\u0437\u0438\u043d\u0430'
print(title)

# Brute force

with open('avito.csv','wb') as f:
    f.write(u'\ufeff'.encode('utf8')) # writes "byte order mark" UTF-8 signature
    writer=csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerow([title.encode('utf8')])

# Example from the documentation for csv module

class UnicodeWriter:
    """
    A CSV writer which will write rows to CSV file "f",
    which is encoded in the given encoding.
    """

    def __init__(self, f, dialect=csv.excel, encoding="utf-8-sig", **kwds):
        # Redirect output to a queue
        self.queue = cStringIO.StringIO()
        self.writer = csv.writer(self.queue, dialect=dialect, **kwds)
        self.stream = f
        self.encoder = codecs.getincrementalencoder(encoding)()

    def writerow(self, row):
        self.writer.writerow([s.encode("utf-8") for s in row])
        # Fetch UTF-8 output from the queue ...
        data = self.queue.getvalue()
        data = data.decode("utf-8")
        # ... and reencode it into the target encoding
        data = self.encoder.encode(data)
        # write to the target stream
        self.stream.write(data)
        # empty queue
        self.queue.truncate(0)

    def writerows(self, rows):
        for row in rows:
            self.writerow(row)

with open('avito2.csv','wb') as f:
    w = UnicodeWriter(f)
    w.writerow([title])

# 3rd party module, install from pip

import unicodecsv
with open('avito3.csv','wb') as f:
    w = unicodecsv.writer(f,encoding='utf-8-sig')
    w.writerow([title])
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 2):

You have to write to the file with the correct encoding, and from your comment I guess, it is `cp1251`:

```
 import io
 title = u'\u0410\u0434\u043c\u0438\u043d\u0438\u0441\u0442\u0440\u0430\u0442\u043e\u0440 \u0438\u043d\u0442\u0435\u0440\u043d\u0435\u0442-\u043c\u0430\u0433\u0430\u0437\u0438\u043d\u0430'
 with io.open('avito.csv', 'a', encoding='cp1251') as output:
     output.write(title + '\n')
```

Comment: in file avito after this code i ' v e got this -   РђРґРјРёРЅРёСЃС‚СЂР°С‚РѕСЂ РёРЅС‚РµСЂРЅРµС‚-РјР°РіР°Р·РёРЅР° . But i'd like to get this cyrillic text  - Администратор интернет-магазина

Comment: Which encoding do you use, to read your file?

Comment: @egorkh This `u' РђРґРјРёРЅРёСЃС‚СЂР°С‚РѕСЂ РёРЅС‚РµСЂРЅРµС'` is `u'Администратор интернет-магазина'.encode('utf8').decode('cp1251')`. That means that the string has been written as utf8 and that you read it as cp1251, what should not happen with Daniel's code.

Comment: The `csv` module which has its own quirks, especially with Python 2.x.